# Count function children and grandchildren, i got children how do i get grandchildren

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, count

im trying to get a count of grandchildren within at dog database and only want dogs with 15 or more children and/or 40 or more grandchildren to get exported to a list. I dont need to se the names of children or grandchildren just a count of them.

I made a fiddle DB to show what i got so fare.

NEW updated 2019.08.23 kl 16:31 
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9f700055c3d0a066b545f9f489fb1801

The database i old and set in a way that i can't change it so i have to work with what i got. I have tryed some of the way i have found on google but all of them seems to be for a more complex DB or i don't get them(most likely the last as i am not very good i sql)

if anyone has any tips or advice then they will be highly appreciated.
I probably could have explained this in a better way had I known more about sql

```
select d2.Id ,d2.Reg , d2.Name , count(d2.id) as Children

from dbo.Dogs d 

left join dbo.Litters D0 on D0.Id = d.LitterId

left join dbo.Dogs D1 on D0.FatherId=D1.ID

left join dbo.Dogs D2 on D0.MotherId=D2.ID

Group by d2.id , d2.name , d2.Reg

having COUNT(*) > 12
```

this is what i got :

```
Id  Reg Name    Children

1   NO23456/2009    Queen   20

8   NO23457/2009    Godess  14
```

what i want is this

```
Id  Reg     Name    Children    Grandchildren

1   NO23456/2009    Queen   20      0

8   NO23457/2009    Godess  14      0
```

What I'm trying to accomplish here is a query where I can define a number of puppies on the mother's side and another number on the father's side. And add a third number to the grandchildren on both sides

> create table dbo.dogs ( ID varchar (255), Reg varchar (255) , Name varchar (255), LitterID varchar (255));
>
> create table dbo.litters (ID int , Dateofbirth date, FatherID int , MotherID int );
>
> INSERT INTO Dogs (id, Reg, NAME, litterid)
>
> VALUES
>   ('11', 'NO34567/2012', 'Fido1', '9000'),('12', 'NO34568/2012', 'Fido2', '9000'),('13', 'NO34569/2012', 'Fido3', '9000'),('14', 'NO34570/2012', 'Fido4', '9000'),('15', 'NO34571/2012', 'Fido5', '9000'),('16', 'NO34572/2014', 'Fido6', '7000'),('17', 'NO34573/2014', 'Fido7', '7000'),
>   ('18', 'NO34574/2014', 'Fido8', '7000'),('19', 'NO34575/2014', 'Fido9', '7000'),('20', 'NO34576/2014', 'Fido10', '7000'),('21', 'NO34577/2014', 'Fido11', '7000'),('22', 'NO34578/2016', 'Fido12', '6000'),('23', 'NO34579/2016', 'Fido13', '6000'),('24', 'NO34580/2016', 'Fido14', '6000'),
>   ('25', 'NO34581/2016', 'Fido15', '6000'),('26', 'NO34582/2016', 'Fido16', '6000'),('27', 'NO34583/2016', 'Fido17', '6000'),('28', 'NO34584/2015', 'Fido18', '5000'),('29', 'NO34585/2015', 'Fido19', '5000'),('30', 'NO34586/2015', 'Fido20', '5000'),('31', 'NO34587/2015', 'Fido21', '5000'),
>   ('32', 'NO34588/2015', 'Fido22', '5000'),('33', 'NO34589/2015', 'Fido23', '5000'),('34', 'NO34590/2015', 'Fido24', '5000'),('35', 'NO34591/2015', 'Fido25', '5000'),('36', 'NO34592/2015', 'Fido26', '5000'),('37', 'NO34593/2017', 'Fido27', '4000'),('38', 'NO34594/2017', 'Fido28', '4000'),
>   ('39', 'NO34595/2017', 'Fido29', '4000'),('40', 'NO34596/2017', 'Fido30', '4000'),('41', 'NO34597/2017', 'Fido31', '4000'),('42', 'NO34598/2017', 'Fido32', '4000'),('43', 'NO34599/2017', 'Fido33', '4000'),('44', 'NO34600/2017', 'Fido34', '4000'),('45', 'NO34601/2014', 'Fido35', '3000'),
>   ('46', 'NO34602/2014', 'Fido36', '3000'),('47', 'NO34603/2014', 'Fido37', '3000'),('48', 'NO34604/2014', 'Fido38', '3000'),('49', 'NO34605/2014', 'Fido39', '3000'),('50', 'NO34606/2014', 'Fido40', '3000'),('51', 'NO34607/2015', 'Fido41', '2000'),('52', 'NO34608/2015', 'Fido42', '2000'),
>   ('53', 'NO34609/2015', 'Fido43', '2000'),('54', 'NO34610/2015', 'Fido44', '2000'),('55', 'NO34611/2015', 'Fido45', '2000'),('56', 'NO34631/2018', 'Fido45jr', '2001'),('57', 'NO34641/2018', 'Fido45jr', '2001'),('58', 'NO34651/2018', 'Fido45jr', '2001'),
>   ('59', 'NO34661/2018', 'Fido45jr', '2001'),('2', 'NO12345/2010', 'king', '8001'),('1', 'NO23456/2009', 'Queen', '7001'),('7', 'NO12346/2010', 'God', '8000'),('8', 'NO23457/2009', 'Godess', '7001'),('9', 'NO12346/2010', 'Devil', '8000'),('5', 'NO12346/2011', 'Princess', '9002');
>
> INSERT INTO Litters (ID, Dateofbirth, FatherID, MotherID)
>
> VALUES
>   ('9000', '2012.04.01', '2', '1'),('5000', '2015.05.01', '2', '1'),('6000', '2016.06.01', '9', '1'),('7000', '2014.04.02', '7', '8'),('4000', '2017.05.02', '2', '8'),('3000', '2014.06.02', '2', '5'),('2000', '2015.04.03', '9', '5'),('2001', '2018.04.03', '23', '55');

Comment: A fiddle link is great, but's even better to include the DDL and DML in the question itself. Also, it would be a hell of a lot easier to work with a minimized sample data. There's plenty of irrelevant data in your fiddle, we don't need that much.

Comment: Why do you join Dogs D1? It is not used anywhere

Comment: Not in this example but i want the same results for male dogs (D1 = Father and D2 = Mother)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your schema right that would work:

```
SELECT d.Id                   AS ParentID,
       d.Name,
       d.Reg,
       COUNT(DISTINCT d1.id)  AS children,
       COUNT(DISTINCT d2.id)  AS grandchildren
FROM   Dogs d
       JOIN dbo.Litters LittersFarther
            ON  LittersFarther.FatherId = d.id
                OR LittersFarther.MotherId = d.id
       LEFT JOIN Dogs d1
            ON  LittersFarther.id = d1.litterid
       LEFT JOIN dbo.Litters Litters2
            ON  Litters2.FatherId = d1.id
                OR Litters2.MotherId = d1.id
       LEFT JOIN Dogs d2
            ON  Litters2.id = d2.litterid
       LEFT JOIN dbo.Litters Litters1
            ON  Litters1.id = d.litterID
WHERE  Litters1.id IS            NULL
GROUP BY
       d.Id,
       d.Name,
       d.Reg
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT case when LittersFarther.FatherId = d.id then d1.id ELSE 0 end) > 12 -- Filter for number of father's children
       OR COUNT(DISTINCT case when LittersFarther.FatherId = d.id then d2.id ELSE 0 end) > 2  -- Filter for number of father's grandchildren   
       OR COUNT(DISTINCT case when LittersFarther.MotherId = d.id then d1.id ELSE 0 end) > 12  -- Filter for number of mother's children
       OR COUNT(DISTINCT case when LittersFarther.MotherId = d.id then d2.id ELSE 0 end) > 4  -- Filter for number of mother's grandchildren
```

Comment: This only looks at the father? or both father and mother? because i only sees the fatherID in the query and when i try it i returns very few results

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplish here is a query where I can define a number of puppies on the mother's side and another number on the father's side. And add a third number to the grandchildren on both sides

Comment: I've edited the solution. Check it out.
I added the MotherID column to Litters table and there is 4 filters now.

Comment: i Like the look and filters but i cant get it to work. i should get a list like this 

    Id Reg Name Children Grandchildren 
    1 NO23456/2009 Queen 20 0 
    8 NO23457/2009 Godess 14 0 

but i get like this 

id Name Sex Children GrandChildren GrandGrandChildren 

just the headings but no data. 
And for me it seem like it will show and count the puppies in the litter not the mother or fathers Puppies

Comment: see the new fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ccd634d83dba24a377edb5d0a4f42163

Comment: Edited it again.

Comment: Thank you for using so much time on this problem and i see now that vi are getting som results but not the correct ones i am soory to say


>id Name Reg Children GrandChildren GrandGrandChildren
>2 king NO12345/2010 4 0 0
>9 Devil NO12346/2010 2 2 0
>1 Queen NO23456/2009 3 1 0
>5 Princess NO12346/2011 2 1 0
>8 Godess NO23457/2009 2 0 0

but i should have been this results :
>2 NO12345/2010 king 28
>23 NO34579/2016 Fido13 4
>7 NO12346/2010 God 6
>9 NO12346/2010 Devil 11
>1 NO23456/2009 Queen 20
>5 NO12346/2011 Princess 11
>55 NO34611/2015 Fido45 4
>8 NO23457/2009 Godess 14

Comment: New Link to :https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9f700055c3d0a066b545f9f489fb1801

Comment: Hoe can Goddes have 14 children if there are only 8 rows in Litters?

Comment: that is because each litterid can have 4-8 puppies connected to it. So if Godess and King get one Litter with 6 puppies then the count should be 6 not 1 even if its only one litterID. then the rows in litters will be one but in dogs the litterid will be repeted 6 times on the mothersid and the fatherid.

but if the mother have two litters with different fathers then motherid will be repeted 6 times with one litterID and then 4 times with another litterID in the table dogs and should get the results of 10

Comment: Then it would be easier to make it without CTE. Just one select and you got it.

Comment: works like a charm in my testDB but gets no results in my real DB. I dont see the differance and no error messages. but thank you for the solution and i have to see if i can spot the differance in my real DB

Comment: i found out that is i changed the statment Where from is NULL to is not NULL it work in my real DB. Thank you so much for all the help.